# In Rails how do I order collection of records where sort_by Ruby method is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a User model and Post model, where User has many Posts. I need to order posts by last_date_modified. Here is code that loops over each user's posts, groups each post based on status, but it doens't order them by last_date_modified.

```
<% @user.posts.uniq.group_by(&:status).sort_by { |s, e| s }.each do | status, posts | %>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= post.created_at %>
        <%= post.title %>
        <%= post.description %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @JTG for formatting my question!

Comment: have you tried to use order("updated_at DESC")

Comment: @railsr where do you place order("updated_at DESC")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you better do this in controller not in your view

```
@user.posts.order("updated_at DESC").uniq.group_by(&:status)...
```

Comment: That seem to have done it. I wrote order(updated_at: :desc), but that didn't work. Thanks @railsr